# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where 0 = admin limit 1)

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I try to make login for admin using ajax.But I run into this error.I don't know where is column 0 come from.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `0` = admin limit 1)

Here is my code

```
public function login()
{
    $username= Input::get('username');
    $password= Input::get('password');
    $admin=array([
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password,
        'level'=>1
        ]);
    if ($this->auth->attempt($admin)) {
        return "ok";
    }
    else {
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{

    use Authenticatable;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ["username","password",'level'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
    public $timestamps = false;


}
```

Comment: add your full error stack in the question.

Comment: @Vikas I just update the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your `$admin` array. You've mixed the two syntaxes for creating arrays and you've accidentally created an array of arrays.

You need to change your `$admin` array to either:

```
$admin = array(
    'username'=>$username,
    'password'=>$password,
    'level'=>1
);
```

or:

```
$admin = [
    'username'=>$username,
    'password'=>$password,
    'level'=>1
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I fix it.